# Delete dynamically allocated memory twice?

Tags: gcc, memory, compiler-construction, delete-operator

First I'd like to point out that I'm using a GNU GCC compiler. I'm using Code::Blocks as my IDE so I don't have to type in all the compiler junk into the Windows DOS command prompt. If I could be more specific about my compiler, what shows up as a line at the bottom of Cod::Blocks when I successfully compile is

```
mingw32-g++.exe -std=c++11 -g
```

Anyways, my question involves using the delete operator to release dynamically allocated memory. When I compile this code snippet:

```
int* x;
x = new int;
delete x;
delete x;
```

I don't get any warnings or errors or crashes. From the book I'm learning C++ from, releasing a pointer to a dynamically allocated memory chuck can only be done once, then the pointer is invalid. If you use delete on the same pointer again, then there will be problems. However, I don't get this problem.

Likewise, if I pass an object by value to a function, so that it is shallow copied, I get no error if I don't have a copy constructor to ensure deep copy (using raw pointers in the object). This means that when the function returns, the shallow copy goes out of scope, and invokes its destructor (where I'm using delete on a pointer). When int main returns, the original object goes out of scope, its destructor is invoked, and that same shallow copied pointer is deleted. But I have no problems.

I tried finding documentation online about the compiler I'm using and couldn't find any. Does this mean that the mingw32 compiler has some sort of default copy constructor it uses? Thus, I don't have to worry about creating copy constructors?

Comment: You don't get any problems because you're lucky.  I'd recommend buying a bunch of Powerball tickets right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler documentation is not likely to be helpful in this case: If it exists, it is likely to list exceptions to the C++ spec.  It's the C++ spec that you need here.

When you delete the same pointer twice, the result--according to the C++ spec--is *undefined*.  The compiler could do anything at all and have it meet spec.  The compiler is allowed to recognize the fault and give an error message, or not recognize the fault and blow up immediately or sometime later.  That your compiler appeared to work *this time* is no indication that the double delete is safe.  It could be mucking up the heap in a way that results in a seg fault much later.

If you do not define a copy constructor, C++ defines one for you.  The default copy constructor does a memberwise copy.

When you have the same object pointed to by multiple pointers, such as you do, consider using [std::smart_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one).